# how do you use wget in python with options

Tags: python, parameters, wget

I'm trying to use the python wget command from the wget module to download files from the web.  The page I'm working with creates the wget command for me.  I just have to execute it.  How (if at all) can I do that using the wget command?  I've tried recreating the text as a parameter in the wget command but that doesn't work.  I don't want to execute the command as an external process as I don't want to require or assume that the user has the Linux etc. wget command on their machine.

The image is the wget command text I'm trying to execute.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I guess it would help to get useful answers if you could provide the command text as plain text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like while it is named `wget` it is not a one to one match - you cannot make it handle all of the arguments you can provide to the linux wget.

See here: https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/src/3001fd1b30aca7e5fe162c9193ccbb951dabb4ea/wget.py#lines-568

Ultimately, it takes a URL and an output file. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Fix is just to require the user to have the unix/windows equivalent of wget installed and run it as a subprocess.